# Change Label metric unit in LibGDX

Tags: libgdx

I'm using Scene2d to build ui for my screen.

```
Stage stage = new Stage(new StretchViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()));
Skin skin = ResourceManager.getSkin("uiskin");
Label label = new Label("my text", skin);
```

When stage.draw() has called, the label appeared in left bottom corner of the screen. But I want to use the viewport with unit size.

```
float ratio = (float)Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
Stage stage = new Stage(new StretchViewport(ratio, 1));
```

In this way I can define size of other actors in percents of screen height - 0.5 , 0,23 ect. And it works well for other Actors, ImageActors, but how I can properly change size of my label? Label draw in the same place, I think, but it is tremendous for the stage, be cause its size is in pixel 183 *10 ect. And

```
label.setBounds(.....);
```

isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the scale on the font. I'm not sure why it doesn't happen automatically, but the fix is to add a line like:

```
font.GetData().setScale(<viewport width>/Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), <viewport height>/Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
```